# Correct use of Netwire (5)

Tags: haskell, frp, netwire

I've been wanting to give FRP a shot for a while now, and yesterday I finally bit the bullet and had a go, using Netwire 5 to begin with (a fairly arbitrary choice in itself, but I have to start somewhere!).  I've managed to get to the point of "code which works" but I've noticed a couple of patterns which I'm not sure are part of how the library is expected to be used or whether they are a symptom that I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

I started with [this tutorial](http://todayincode.tumblr.com/post/96914679355/almost-a-netwire-5-tutorial), which was enough to get me up and running pretty easily -- I now have a spinning cube controlled by a simple "incrementing number" wire:

```
spin :: (HasTime t s, Monad m) => Wire s e m a GL.GLfloat
spin = integral 0 . 5
```

and the application will quit when "Esc" is pressed, making use of the wires supplied in [netwire-input-glfw](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire-input-glfw):

```
shouldQuit :: (Monoid e, Functor m, Monad m) => Wire s e (GLFWInputT m) a a
shouldQuit = keyPressed GLFW.Key'Escape
```

An important distinction between these is that `spin` never inhibits -- it should always return some value -- while `shouldQuit` inhibits all the time; until the key is actually pressed in which case I quit the application.

The thing that makes me uneasy is the way I end up having to use these wires.  Right now, it looks something like this:

```
(wt', spinWire') <- stepWire spinWire st $ Right undefined
((qt', quitWire'), inp'') <- runStateT (stepWire quitWire st $ Right undefined) inp'

case (qt', wt') of
  (Right _, _) -> return ()
  (_, Left _)  -> return () -- ???
  (_, Right x) -> --do things, render, recurse into next frame
```

There are two things about this pattern that make me feel uncomfortable.  First, the fact that I pass `Right undefined` to both calls to `stepWire`.  I think (if my understanding is correct) that this parameter is for sending events to a wire, and that since my wires don't make any use of events this is "safe", but it feels bad (**EDIT** maybe "events" is the wrong word here -- the tutorial describes it as for "blocking values", but the point still stands -- I never intend to block and don't make use of the `e` parameter anywhere in my wire).  I looked to see if there was a version of `stepWire` for the situation where you know you never have an event and you wouldn't respond to it even if you did have one, but couldn't see one.  I tried making the wires `e` parameter `()` and then passing `Right ()` everywhere, which feels marginally less dirty than `undefined`, but still doesn't quite seem to represent my intent.

Similarly, the return value is also an `Either`.  That's perfect for the `shouldQuit` wire, but notice I have to pattern match on `wt'`, the output of the `spin` wire.  I really don't know what it would mean for that to inhibit, so I just `return ()`, but I can imagine this getting unwieldy as the number of wires increases, and again, it just doesn't seem that representative of my intent -- to have a wire which never inhibits and which I can rely upon always to hold the next value.

So although I have code which works, I'm left with the uneasy feeling that I'm "doing it wrong" somehow, and since Netwire 5 is fairly new it's difficult to find examples of "idiomatic" code that I can check against and see if I'm near the mark.  Is this how the library is intended to be used or am I missing something?

**EDIT**: I've managed to resolve the second problem I mention (pattern matching on the `Either` result of `spin`) by combining `spin` and `shouldQuit` into a single `Wire`:

```
shouldContinuePlaying :: (Monoid e, Functor m, Monad m) => Wire s e (GLFWInputT m) a a
shouldContinuePlaying = keyNotPressed GLFW.Key'Escape

game :: (HasTime t s, Monoid e, Functor m, Monad m) => Wire s e (GLFWInputT m) a GL.GLfloat
game = spin . shouldContinuePlaying
```

Stepping this wire gives me a much more sensible return value -- if it's `Left` I can quit, otherwise I have the piece of data to work with.  It also hints at a greater degree of composability than my original method.

I still have to pass `Right undefined` as the input to this new wire though.  Admittedly, there's only one of them now, but I'm still not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: I tend not to use effects in my wires. Events are passed to the “main wire”, while the monad is left polymorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top level of your program, you're going to have some wire that has (abbreviated) type `Wire a b`. This is going to need to be passed something of type `a` and it will return something of type `b` every time you take a step. For example, both `a` and `b` can be some `WorldState` for a game or maybe `[RigidBody]` for a physics simulator. In my opinion, it's OK to pass `Right undefined` at the top level.

That being said, you're ignoring the important `Alternative` instance of `Wire a b` for the input wires. It provides an operator `<|>` that works in a very nice way:

Suppose we have two wires:

```
w1 :: Wire a b
w2 :: Wire a b
```

If w1 inhibits, then

```
w1 <|> w2 == w2
```

If w1 doesn't inhibit, then

```
w1 <|> w2 == w1
```

This means that `w1 <|> w2` will only inhibit if *both* `w1` and `w2` inhibit. This is great, this means that we can do things like:

```
spin :: (HasTime t s, Monad m) => Wire s e m a GL.GLfloat
spin = integral 0 . (10 . keyPressed GLFW.Key'F <|> 5)
```

When you press `F`, you will spin twice as fast!

If you want to change the semantics of a wire after pressing a button, you have to be a bit more creative, but not much. If your wire behaves differently, it means you're doing some sort of switch. The [documentation for switches](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire-5.0.1/docs/Control-Wire-Switch.html) mostly requires you to [follow the types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376120/confused-about-diagrams-of-yampa-switches/25396338#25396338).

Here's a wire that will act like the identity wire until you press the given key, and will then inhibit forever:

```
trigger :: GLFW.Key -> GameWire a a
trigger key =
  rSwitch mkId . (mkId &&& ((now . pure mkEmpty . keyPressed key) <|> never))
```

With this you can do cool things like:

```
spin :: (HasTime t s, Monad m) => Wire s e m a GL.GLfloat
spin = integral 0 . spinSpeed
  where
    spinSpeed = 5 . trigger GLFW.Key'F --> 
                -5 . trigger GLFW.Key'F -->
                spinSpeed
```

This will toggle the spinner between going forwards and backwards whenever you hit `F`.

Comment: I think my answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745934/kleisli-arrow-in-netwire-5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992299/console-interactivity-in-netwire also helps